# Dynamic Sitemap for Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: php, .htaccess, sitemap, google-search-console

I want to make a dynamic sitemap for Google Webmaster tools. But for some reason, I can't make it work. I write some lines in the htaccess for these purposes (RewriteRule), and it work fine. In fact, validation is OK: [validation](http://www.validome.org/google/validate?url=http://universidades.en-la-argentina.com.ar/sit%20emap_articulos.xml&lang=en&googleTyp=SITEMAP)

But Google print this error every time (here is the english translation):

> We were unable to read your Sitemap. It may contain an entry that can not recognize. Validate the sitemap before re-upload

Weirdly, when I open sitemap.php in the browser and I save the file as xml, Google doesn't print any error.

What's the problem?

EDITED.
Here is the URL:[Dynamic Sitemap](http://universidades.en-la-argentina.com.ar/sitemap_articulos.xml)

Comment: Can you post the exact URL to your sitemap file?

Comment: http://universidades.en-la-argentina.com.ar/sitemap_articulos.xml

Comment: No, it isn't a 404 error. I open the URL in my browser. Here is the URL: http://universidades.en-la-argentina.com.ar/sitemap_articulos.xml